# How to disable TLS1.1 on Undertow (JDK8)

Tags: undertow

In my Java 8 project I'm using the [Undertow webserver](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/index.html#maven) (v2.0.25). This is a standalone setup, there is NO WildFly involved.

I want to disable all the TLS protocols below TLSv1.2 for better security. But all the documentation that I can find is for WildFly which, again, I am NOT using.

In Spring Boot, I could set the `server.ssl.enabled-protocols` system property.

In WildFly, I could set

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="sslRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
```

The Undertow documentation is disappointingly lacking.

How can I set/restrict the enabled protocols?

Answer (score 1):

by using `Undertow.builder()` what you want is `setSocketOption` method like this:

```
Undertow.builder()//add your build code like https listener, server options, etc
        .setSocketOption(Options.SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS, Sequence.of("TLSv1.2","TLSv1.3"))
```

the above call will disable all TLS versions below 1.2, `setSocketOption` works on XNIO level which is the transport layer of undertow, `Options` and `Sequence` classes also come from XNIO.

Notice that I've added TLS 1.3 which is the latest version as of time of writing and supported by all evergreen browsers(but not IE). be sure to use a provider that supports it though, if you're using JDK SSL provider then make sure you're using java 11+., otherwise see your provider's docs, a SSL provider that supports TLS1.3 is google Conscrypt found [here](https://github.com/google/conscrypt)